# How to implement simple POST, GET, and DELETE in python

Tags: python, rest, post, get, pinterest

Short version: Can I just use the Requests module for POST, GET, and DELETE?

I'm trying to use the Pinterest REST API. ([Pinterest API Explorer](https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/api-explorer/?))

I'm going the simple route and just manually got my authentication token via oauth, so basically all I need to know how to do is POST, GET, and DELETE to a specific URL and also include the parameters, then return a json.

I really only need three API functions, list authorized user's followers (GET), follow user (POST), and unfollow user (DELETE). The only param I need for any of those is my access_token that I got manually.

It seems like a simple problem, but there's about 5 python Pinterest API wrappers, none of them complete, some of them not working at all. I've looked at the pycurl, httplib, and requests modules. They all look like they have a simple enough method for GET, but it gets more complicated with POST and maybe DELETE. It seems like it should be super simple, a function that takes a method (POST/GET/DELETE/etc), a url, and a set of parameters, so why is it more complicated than that? If it were that easy, I don't understand why all these API wrappers would be half done since it theoretically should be as simple as calling a function with those 3 parameters (with an array for the 3rd parameter) for every function in the API.

In the Requests python package, there's this function under the RequestMethods class:
def request(self, method, url, fields=None, headers=None, **urlopen_kw)

Looks like I understand everything except what the headers are and the **urlopen_kw, but I think it should work without those to variables, correct?

I'd appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Answer to short version: Yes.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html):

> Here is an example of doing a PUT request using Request:
>
> ```
> import urllib.request
> DATA = b'some data'
> req = urllib.request.Request(url='http://localhost:8080', data=DATA,method='PUT')
> with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as f:
>     pass
> print(f.status)
> print(f.reason)
> ```

In your case the method would be 'POST', 'Delete' or whatever you like.

If you want to make more complex requests, have a look at this [guide](http://www.diveintopython3.net/http-web-services.html) for the [httplib2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/httplib2) library - it's worth reading.